# Connecting to Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg

When I try to call Rblpapi library I receive the following:

> library(Rblpapi)
>   Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/Users/Library/R/3.1/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so':
>     dlopen(/Users/Library/R/3.1/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libblpapi3_64.so
>     Referenced from: /Users/Library/R/3.1/library/Rblpapi/libs/Rblpapi.so
>     Reason: image not found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘Rblpapi’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rblpapi’

Comment: It says the image isn't found, is it there? Also, you should upgrade your R version

Answer (score 0):

Briefly:

1. Your binary seems to be out of sort. Reinstalling usually fixes that.
2. We prefer bug reports for the project as [issue tickets](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/issues) on GitHub.
3. You don't connect *RStudio* to Bloomberg. RStudio is *just* a (rather excellent) IDE for R.
4. We as developers run this all day, on the command-line, in ESS and in RStudio. See 1.

Comment: install.packages("Rblpapi")
Installing package into ‘/Users/afsaneh/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

The downloaded binary packages are in
 /var/folders/c_/jdgk1bp13x5_58nddh8s2dnh0000gn/T//RtmpOmSj08/downloaded_packages

Comment: Is the problem related to location of downloaded binary packages? How can I change it? Thank you

Comment: You confused _installed to_  (in `/Users/afsaneh/Library/R/3.1/library`) with _temporary files downloaded to_ (the other, and this one does not matter).  If you have a _minimally reproducible example_ please file an GH issue per 2. above.

Comment: @Hack-R ESS is an add-on to the Emacs editor: [Emacs Speaks Statistics](http://ess.r-project.org/).